# How to backup a MySQL database without slowing the application?

Tags: mysql, performance, backup, myisam

I was wondering about our database backup strategy: Right now our sysadmins backup our database every 8 hours. I don't really know how the do it, but while the backup is running our application response time goes through the roof. So every 8 hours, the application is slow and sometimes even produces errors.

Is there a way to backup a MySQL database with MyISAM tables without slowing application code and still get a consistent backup?

Comment: why dont your sys admin automate it with cron, and do it during off peak hours

Comment: This of course is automated. There is no "off peak hours", and even if it was, once a day would not be nearly often enough. Even every 8 hours is a problem when things break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the backup with binlogs is definitely faster, you could also check out setting up another server as a slave and take backup from that to remove the application slowdown completely.

Maybe you could research how they do it today, if they just do mysql dumps then ask them to rethink.

MYSQL servers can be ran as either master or slave servers. In a master->slave mode one server retrieves all mysql inserts and updates(master) and all the slaves only serve selects. the master updates the slaves. What you do then is just do the backup from the slave.

The master doesnt know that a backup happens and it doesn't slow it down at all. check out dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html for more info about replication.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do next week, but wanted to start the discussion with a rough idea how to tackle this. Can you elaborate on the slave thing?

Comment: MYSQL servers can be ran as either master or slave servers. 

In a master->slave mode one server retrieves all mysql inserts and updates(master) and all the slaves only serve selects. the master updates the slaves. 

What you do then is just do the backup from the slave. The master doesnt know that a backup happens and it doesn't slow it down at all.

check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html for more info about replication.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Sounds pretty rad compared to our current setup, hope the sysadmins will like it as much as I do. Does the slave have to be an extra box can it run on the same server?

Comment: I suppose it can be ran on the same server, not looked into that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Having not implemented this yet myself I can just point you in the [possibly] right direction: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html

The idea is to stream out the writes to a buffer log, pick those up in a second server, and then make backups of that server.

Comment: This seems to be the direction to go. Replication on slaves, that are then used for backup.